# Maximise a groups probability of reaching a score within PuLP

Tags: python, distribution, linear-programming, pulp

Using python, I have a linear programming solution in Pulp which selects 6 players within a budget constraint whilst maximising a specified parameter.

However, I want to be able to maximise a probability parameter of *each team of 6 players*.

Namely, I want to be able to input a mean and standard deviation for each player, and then maximise the percentage chance of *each team* reaching a predetermined score. This requires summing the means and standard deviations of the 6 players in each team, then calculating the percentage chance of them surpassing this score (I have been using numpy.norm to do this).

The problem I am having is that I am not sure if it is possible to maximise this parameter within a linear programming module like pulp. I can not get it to maximise the probability after summing each teams mean and standard deviation.

I have tried estimating this value by multiplying each individuals mean and standard deviation by 6, thus creating a dummy team, and calculating the probability of reaching the predetermined score, then scaling back down and maximising the sum of these values in each team. This gets close but is not as accurate as I want. This is the code I have so far:

lineup dataframe:

| index | mu | std | Salary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Rory McIlroy | 73.450198 | 10.455766 | 11100. |
| Scottie Scheffler | 72.652175 | 9.477475 | 11000. |
| Jon Rahm | 73.033862 | 10.293721 | 10800. |
| Justin Thomas | 73.886648 | 10.426305 | 10500. |
| Collin Morikawa | 68.409628 | 10.588617 | 10300. |

```
target_score = 600

limit = 50000
lineup_im = lineup2.set_index('index')

w = lineup_im.Salary
v = lineup_im.mu
z = lineup_im['std']

items = list(sorted(lineup_im.index))
# Create model
m = LpProblem("Knapsack", LpMaximize)

# Variables
x = LpVariable.dicts('p', items, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=LpInteger)

# Objective
m += sum((((1-(norm(loc=v[i]*6, scale=z[i]*6).cdf(target_score)))))*x[i] for i in items)/6
   
# Constraint
m += sum(w[i]*x[i] for i in items) <= limit

m += sum(x[i] for i in items) == 6

# Optimize

m.solve()
```

Is there a way to do this within Pulp or another LP module in python?

Answer (score 2):

Define decision variable x_i to indicate whether player i is selected for the team. From the basics of independent random variables, if we define mu_i to be the mean for each player i and sd_i to be their standard deviation, then:

```
mu_team = \sum_i mu_i*x_i
var_team = \sum_i sd_i^2*x_i
sd_team = sqrt(var_team)
```

You seek to maximize the probability that a normal random variable with mean mu_team and standard deviation sd_team exceeds some target score S. Conveniently, this is equivalent to minimizing the Z-score of the value S for that random variable:

```
z_team = (S-mu_team) / sd_team
```

It's now clear that you could reformulate your optimization model as minimizing z_team subject to your budget and team size constraints. However, z_team is non-linear --- it's a linear function of the decision variables divided by the square root of another linear function of the decision variables. In general mixed integer optimization problems with non-linear objective functions are not so trivial to solve; you won't be able to do it "out of the box" with pulp.

Not all is lost, though! Notice that we're basically balancing quantity `S-mu_team` with quantity `sd_team`. If we can construct teams with `mu_team > S`, then we'd ideally like teams with large `mu_team` and small `sd_team`, which enables as negative a `z_team` value as possible. If we could build a tradeoff curve between achievable `mu_team` and `sd_team` values, we could quickly identify the best achievable `z_team` value. Similarly, if all teams have `mu_team < S`, then we'd ideally like teams with large mu_team and large sd_team to get a `z_team` value as close as possible to 0; again, a tradeoff curve would be helpful.

This leads us to a simple solution:

1. Maximize `mu_team` subject to budget and team size constraints. Call the best achievable `mu_team` value `M`. In the special case of `M=S`, the best achievable `z_team` value is 0, and you are done. Otherwise, continue.
2. Build an efficient frontier trading off `mu_team` and `sd_team`:

- If `M > S`, then maximize `mu_team - alpha*var_team` for various constants `alpha >= 0`
- If `M < S`, then maximize `mu_team + alpha*var_team` for various constants `alpha >= 0`

3. Compute `z_team` for each solution in your efficient frontier, and select the one with the smallest `z_team` value.

Note that each of the optimization problems in steps 1 and 2 now have a linear objective value (both `mu_team` and `var_team` are linear in the decision variables), so they will be easily solvable with pulp.

Comment: Interesting idea & approach, but I'm (a) not sure how any solver would help with step 2 as the solver identifies a singular best, not enough to build a frontier.  And (b), you're still stuck w/ some broad enumeration across said frontier because the relationship between `mu_team` and `sd_team` is not strictly defined, and the jump to z_team is nonlinear.  I think I'd still do some pre-sort and just enumerate it all, unless the initial pool is too vast.

Comment: @AirSquid you solve repeatedly with different alpha to build an efficient frontier. In my experience z_team often changes quite smoothly along the frontier, since the frontier smoothly trades off mean and standard deviation. Yes, your comment is well taken that it's simplest to enumerate (just a few lines of code), but this is clearly untenable even with a few hundred golfers or slightly larger teams, which is why I suggested this approach using the tool from the question.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with building efficient frontiers, but I will certainly look in to this solution. Part of the problem that I failed to mention in my question, is that ideally I would not like to find only the best lineup, but the top x amount of lineups that meet certain constraints (such as an individual must be in ~10% of all lineups). I'm not sure if I would be able to do that with this method.
Is there any other solver that would be more up for this task? Not even necessarily in python?

Comment: @will The issue is not the solver/language (e.g. pulp/python versus something else), but the problem instance itself. Some optimization problems are easy and some are hard. Optimizing the z-score is much harder than optimizing the mean, and optimizing many lineups with some joint properties is much harder than optimizing one. As a first step, I'd suggest you ask a new question with the actual task you want accomplished -- little details like one versus multiple lineups make a huge difference!

Comment: Understood. I don’t think I fully explained the problem and was hoping that a simpler question would yield a simpler solution to my overall problem, I think I’ll take some time to do more research and formulate a better question. From looking more in depth it does look like there are python libraries that can solve stochastic integer problems, I’ll update with any solutions I end up finding. All the help I have had on this thread has been very useful regardless.

Comment: @AirSquid I made the idea quite a bit more concrete at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73171090/3093387 , where I used this sort of idea to obtain provably optimal z-scores very quickly using branch-and-bound.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site and nice post w/ data!

You have a chicken vs. egg problem here...  Let me explain...

The parameter that you want to get to is the CDF of the *team* score, which, if you assume it is normally distributed is the sum of the means of the player's scores with a variance that is a sum of the player's variances...  That's how it works for Norm distribution, right?

So, all of those things are known values (parameters) in your problem, based on the player data.  You just haven't calculated the team's CDF for all of the possible teams.  The problem is you cannot do that as some kind of callback *after* using the optimizer to pick team membership, it must be done in advance.  `pulp` solver does not have the ability/linkages to make calls to `numpy` to get the CDF "on the fly".  So you have a couple options...

1. You could reformulate your problem in terms of the teams and then expand your data set and just have a binary variable for which team is selected, but that seems kind of like a waste, because you are essentially having the solver just picking the single best team, with only one constraint (total salary), which makes me think you should just brute force this (see below.)
2. You could just brute force this.  If you are considering 100 players and you are choosing 6, that is combin(100, 6) ~ 1 billion.  So I would use put the data into dictionaries for fast lookup, use itertools to run through the combinations, first screen for total salary cap, and if that passes, compute the team CDF/p-value for the target score, and keep track of the max value

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have attempted to enumerate the problem, and loop using itertools whilst keeping track of the top 10 lineups within the price constraint. This is quicker than my previous attempt to brute force the problem, but would still take 10+ hours to run from what I am seeing - unless there is a more efficient way to write the code. I am working with roughly 140 golfers and need combinations of 6, but I am also looking to use the same code in other sports where the player pools are much larger and have many more combinations, so it is only really a short term solution